# remove Congratulations popup at the end of infinitescroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

How can I remove the popup at the end of infinitescroll. The one where is says Congratulations.
I tried setting the message to empty "" but that doesn't stop the black popup from appearing.

```
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: ""
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
donetext     : "I think we've hit the end, Jim" ,
             // text displayed when all items have been retrieved
             // default: "<em>Congratulations, you've reached the end of the internet.</em>"
```

[Infinite Scroll Documentation](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

as default, he say your `congratulations`.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, not sure if you read the first part of my post but I'm trying to remove the popup not set the text in it. I just don't want it to show at all when it reaches the end.

Comment: Yes, but your pop-up dos not come from `donetext`? what i'm meen is, try to remove any string named as `congratulation`. I think if you search something like that, maybe can solve your problem.

Comment: donetext is not even a variable in paulirish/infinite-scroll version 2.0b2.120519. I also don't want to alter code in the plugin. I just need to Know if there is a method that I can use to remove this feature.

Comment: did you try this ? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tumblr-themes/C8prcggi7oY

Comment: Try what? I read this link and there is no information about removing the popup? unless I'm missing something on that page

Answer (score 0):

Years later, a software engineer will discover this question in the basement under several layers of dust and detritus. So... The documentation is not very good for this plugin, despite the author. It is not obvious, but if you want to remove the popup with the message, simply set the `finishedMsg` variable in the `options` object to an empty string:

```
jQuery('#main').infinitescroll({
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: ""
    }
}, function() {});
```

... And voila! The plugin will not show the popup at all.